# Keypress event does not work?

Tags: vb6, keypress

Im coding in vb6 and for fun thought I would play around with the keypress event to make things move. I came to the quick realization that a VERY limited number of keys would respond to key press events. i wanted to use the arrow keys but it seems although there are reserved commands for them (`VBKeyUp`,`VBKeyDown`,`VBKeyRight`,`VBKeyLeft`) they just dont do anything. is there an explanation for this or do they just have no support? Code im using is below.

```
Private Sub ListView67_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
If KeyAscii = vbKeyUp Then
Command1_Click
End If

If KeyAscii = vbKeyDown Then
Command4_Click
End If

If KeyAscii = vbKeyRight Then
Command2_Click
End If

If KeyAscii = vbKeyLeft Then
Command3_Click
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The KeyUp and KeyDown events support a wider range of keys including the arrow keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use KeyDown event instead of KeyPress

```
Private Sub ListView67_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
If KeyCode = vbKeyUp Then
Command1_Click
End If

If KeyCode = vbKeyDown Then
Command4_Click
End If

If KeyCode = vbKeyRight Then
Command2_Click
End If

If KeyCode = vbKeyLeft Then
Command3_Click
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: that makes sense but the keydown event does not trigger with this code.

Comment: @NickHallick This code should work as long as the ListView67 control has focus.

Comment: @Jac the keydown event triggers but keyascii does not fill with anything when i press an arrow key

Comment: @NickHallick Do you mean the KeyCode? I have tried salih's code and it is working for me.

Comment: @NickHallick What is your exact requirement?. This code should work if the ListView67 control has focused.

Comment: i got it, i forgot to switch over keyascii to keycode. sorry for any confusion!